# GDI+ memory utilization

Tags: c#, gdi+, cpu-usage

I have developed some components in c# using GDI+ technology...I am using invalidate function for repainting the components.. After doing some research and checking the CPU utilization..i can see that when invalidate function is called,suddenly the CPU usage increases and after some time it is released..this is ok when component repaint is called  sometimes.. But in my case the component i have made is called again and again and at peak times..suddenly the CPU utilization goes to 100%...and system seems to hung..I have done lot of code optimization but it seems invalidate method just kills the whole performance.. I just want to know..what actually is called in this method..and what are the best practises to make best use of this method...

Comment: Don't use GDI+, this is exactly why it should be avoided. Use something that is hardware accelerated, like `BitmapImage` in the PresentationCore assembly.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to memory leaks. Could you please update the text or the tags.

Comment: @vcsjones: you are right,but that means i have to make a switch from current architecture to WPF and make all the components once again..this is something which wont be feasible to do currently...as i have around 35 custom components made using GDI+.

Comment: It's plenty possible that you are leaking memory or resources. Turn on the Handles column in the task manager and watch it. Disposing of all things disposable is incredibly important with GDI+.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen : sorry...i will remove this..the tag should have been memory utilization.. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Perfview to profile your application: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567

2) Invalidate method should not actually draw. It just tells OS which are needs to be redrawn. It's the OnPaint method which actually draws. Check your drawing method. Normally, GDI based application queries dirty region to limit areas of redrawing.